# How to get circle shaped image in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have been trying to mask a UIImage into a circle.

```
extension UIImageView{

func setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl url: String){

    if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
            self.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and provide an [example] describing your problem. It's not clear right now what you are asking.

Comment: i meant xcode @Joakim Danielson

Comment: The code you posted does not seem relevant to the question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is something like `self.image.layer.cornerRadius = self.image.frame.width / 2` - to perfect circle corner need to be width(or height) / 2